# The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

> Windows return code: 0x21c7, state: 15. Failure to register a SPN
>   might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos.
>   This is an informational message. Further action is only required if
>   Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if
>   the SPN has not been manually registered.

I am getting above error whenever I restart my SQL service. I changed it from current service account to local account and was able to connect to SSMS from local machine, but if I am using current service account then this error is coming and in SSMS the error is :

> The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.

The password is not changed for this service account.

Answer (score 8):

You specifically get error "0x21c7, state: 15" when an attempt is made to register the SPN which already exists, but possibly under different account.

When you run SQL Service under local system account, an SPN is registered under the Computer Object in AD. You can confirm from below:

```
setspn -l ComputerName
```

In above results, If you see any SPNs for MSSQLSvc then they need to be dropped with below commands on AD (You need to have Domain Admin permissions for this) so that you can then register SPN under new Service account:

```
setspn -d MSSQLSvc/FQDN:XXXXXXXXXX ComputerName
```

Once the above is done, restart SQL Service under the Service Account adn it should successfully register the SPN under the new Service account and you will be able to confirm by running the below command:

```
setspn -l DomainName\LoginName
```

Reference: http://www.b-blog.info/en/changing-service-account-for-ms-sql-server-2012-and-the-following-issues.html

You could also use Microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server to automatically detect and fix such SPN Issues:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2013/05/21/new-tool-microsoft-kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server-is-ready-to-resolve-your-kerberosconnectivity-issues/

Answer (score 3):

According to [KB article 811889](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811889):

> Because you might not use a domain administrator account to run the
>   SQL Server service (to prevent security risk), the computer that is
>   running SQL Server cannot create its own SPN. Therefore, you must
>   manually create an SPN for your computer that is running SQL Server if
>   you want to use Kerberos authentication when you connect to a computer
>   that is running SQL Server.

In the same article, there are several options to remedy this problem. I would try creating an SPN manually.

To manually set up an SPN for SQL Server, refer to [KB article 319723 (excerpted below)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119195533/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319723), where it is recommended to use the `ADSIEdit` tool on the domain controller. Scroll down to *Step 3: Configure the SQL Server service to create SPNs dynamically* on that article.

You have to modify permissions to allow `Read servicePrincipalName` and `Write servicePrincipalName` for the SQL Server service account, and it's quite convoluted.

For what it's worth, sometimes deleting a server name from there gets SPN to work, too. Good luck!

---

The steps from [KB 319723 (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119195533/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319723) are:

1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type Adsiedit.msc, and then click **OK**.
2. In the ADSI Edit snap-in, expand **Domain [DomainName]**, expand **DC= *RootDomainName***, expand **CN=Users**, right-click **CN= *AccountName*** , and then click **Properties**.
3. In the **CN= *AccountName* Properties** dialog box, click the **Security** tab.
4. On the **Security** tab, click **Advanced**.
5. In the **Advanced Security Settings** dialog box, make sure that **SELF** is listed under **Permission entries**.

   - If **SELF** is not listed, click **Add**, and then add **SELF**.
6. Under **Permission entries**, click **SELF**, and then click **Edit**.
7. In the **Permission Entry** dialog box, click the **Properties** tab.
8. On the **Properties** tab, click **This object only** in the **Apply onto** list, and then click to select the check boxes for the following permissions under **Permissions**:

   - **Read servicePrincipalName**
   - **Write servicePrincipalName**
9. Click **OK** two times.
10. In the **CN= *AccountName* Properties** dialog box, click **Attribute Editor**.
11. Under **Attributes**, click **servicePrincipalName** in the **Attribute** column, and then click **Edit**.
12. In the **Multi-valued String Editor** dialog box, remove the service principle names (SPNs) for the instances of SQL Server that use this SQL Server service account.
13. Exit the ADSI Edit snap-in.

> **NOTE:** these steps are included for reference as the original KB page has been taken down. Important context & informative notes exist on the [linked snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119195533/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319723) that are not excerpted here.

Answer (score -2):

I am able to solve the issue with this post.

https://cmatskas.com/fixing-error-cannot-generate-sspi-context-after-changing-sql-service-account/

The recommendation is to grant the domain account that the SQL Server service is using the necessary AD privileges to read and write Service Principal Names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ExploringApple. Try to include more content than just links as answers, though, since dead links render answers like this useless.

Comment: Point noted, thanks for the clarification and agree!